# Deserialize an XML array

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I got deserializing working with single element. But when I have array of xml elements my code is not working

Below is my code.

XML:

```
<data>
    <cars>
        <body>
            <color>blue<color>
            <type>sedan</type>
        </body>
        <details>
            <year>2016</year>
            <make>Infiniti</make>
        </details>
    </cars>
    <cars>
        <body>
            <color>white<color>
            <type>SUV</type>
        </body>
        <details>
            <year>2016</year>
            <make>Lexus</make>
        </details>
    </cars>
</data>
```

Dto

```
[XmlRoot("cars")]
public class CarDetails
{
        [XmlElement("body")]
        public Body BodyList { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("details")]
        public DetailsList details { get; set; }
}

public class Body
        {
            public string Color { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
        }

public class DetailsList
        {
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public string Make { get; set; }
        }
```

Below is the code for deserializing:

```
CarDetails[] details;
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarDetails[]));
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(output))
            {
                details= (CarDetails[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
```

Please help me how to deserialize XML array

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your XML is invalid.

```
<color>blue<color>
```

you forgot to close color here.
Secondly, it's better not to do it on yourself. Better to make it using some tools. Like [online XML to C# generator](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/). You can find similar ones for JSON. In my case it have given this result (take look at Data class):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="body")]
public class Body {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="color")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="details")]
public class Details {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="year")]
    public string Year { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="make")]
    public string Make { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="cars")]
public class Cars {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="body")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="details")]
    public Details Details { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName="data")]
public class Data {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="cars")]
    public List<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wow, cool!, Thanks a lot for XML 2 C# link!